# What is the name of the syntax standard Keithley is using for remote control over serial?

Tags: serial, communication, programming, rs232, remote

Keithey (and other manufacturers) have a standard syntax for communicating over serial. Typically, commands look like ([source](http://research.physics.illinois.edu/bezryadin/labprotocol/Keithley2400Manual.pdf)):

```
:SENSe:FUNCtion “RESistance”
:SENSe:RESistance:RANGe <n>
:SENSe:RESistance:MODE <name>
:SENSe:RESistance:OCOMpensated <state>
:SENSe:VOLTage:PROTection <n>
:SENSe:CURRent:PROTection <n>
:SOURce:FUNCtion <name>
:SYSTem:RSENse <state>
:OUTPut <state>
:READ?
```

What is the the of this standard syntax?

Comment: Standard Commands for Programmable Instruments (SCPI)?  See wikipedia.

Comment: ":SENSs:FUNCtion..." Chris is right, that looks like SCPI to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard Commands for Programmable Instruments (SCPI)? See wikipedia. -Chris